# MQL4メタエディターで、取引関数OrderOpenTimeについて教えてください。

Tags: mql4

MQL4メタエディターでコードを書いていました。
買いと売り１つづつの両建てが可能な内容で書きました。
取引関数OrderOpenTimeでエントリーしたロウソク足の日時を算出しようとしましたが、エントリーが買いと売り両建てしている場合、買いと売りそれぞれどのように算出していいかわかりません。
助けが必要となりました。

今のところ、一つのエントリーに対しては以下のコードで問題なく取得出来ています。
しかし、２つのエントリーに対しては対応できていません。

```c
for(int i = OrdersTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(OrderSelect(i, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_TRADES) == false) break;
    if(OrderMagicNumber() != MagicNumber) continue;
    if(OrderSymbol() != Symbol()) continue;

    oder_shift = iBarShift(Symbol(),Period(),OrderOpenTime() , false );
}
```

OrderOpenTimeをiBarShiftを使うため、書きました。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 検索するとこんな記事が見つかるので、これらのサイトを調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [取引の関数](https://mql4.metasys-seeker.com/category/index/%e5%8f%96%e5%bc%95%e3%81%ae%e9%96%a2%e6%95%b0/), [OrderOpenTime](https://yukifx.web.fc2.com/sub/reference/16_trade_func/cone/trade_opentime.html), [約定した時間を返してくれる関数OrderOpenTime()の使い方【MQL4】](https://buco-bianco.com/mql4-orderopentime-function/), [【MQL4勉強プログラミング】選択した注文の約定日時を取得する方法とは？](https://mt4-traders.com/reference/orderopentime/), [【MQL】OrderSelect関数で活用できる関数についてわかりやすく説明してみた](https://creator.fx-ea-system-project.com/mt4-expert-adviser/orderselect-function/)

Comment: ありがとうございます。
今のところ１つのエントリーに対しての対応はできていて、これが２つになるとできない状況です。
質問文に、現状のコードを追記しました。

Comment: 「対応できていない」の詳細は何かということを掘り下げてみた方が良いと思われます。直接的な関連は無さそうですが、こちらの記事が参考になるかも。[How can I take multiple trades when condition is satisfied?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52003452/9014308)

Comment: がんばってみます。ありがとうございます。